Как ответить на всплывающие окно в webdriver selenium
Делаю скрипт для себя, и открывая ссылку зум нужно нажать "Отмена" 
Пытаюсь уже пару дней но все никак не нахожу ответ

дубликаты, возможно, где-то здесь

Вроде-бы все пересмотрел но ответа не нашел(
